# pyppeteer ghost cursor installing doesn't work

Tags: python

I have tried `pip install pyppeteer-ghost-cursor==0.2.3`
but it returned

```
Collecting pyppeteer-ghost-cursor==0.2.3
  Using cached pyppeteer_ghost_cursor-0.2.3-py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
Collecting bezier
  Using cached bezier-2021.2.12.tar.gz (313 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      The BEZIER_INSTALL_PREFIX environment variable must be set.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

What can i do now to install this package pls help
Im using windows 10 to install this package but don't really work

Comment: Have you tried setting the environment variable as the error message says?

Answer (score 1):

[INSTALL_PREFIX environment variable must be set error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73339608/install-prefix-environment-variable-must-be-set-error)

I had the same problem. You have to downgrade to Python 3.9.x unfortunately.